# Django admin set and user view permission

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I need to add to my django application the view permission. I need that some users have the permission to see all values inserted in some models but do not have the permission of adding/changing/deleting them.

In accordance to Django docs I've added "default_permissions" expression to my model meta information,for example:

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    name= Models.TextField(verbose_name=u"Name")

class Meta:
    default_permissions = ('add', 'change', 'delete', 'view')
```

Then I've changed my group permission and added it to some users. The problem is that when these users go to the view page they receive an 403 error.

Do I have to change my "changelist_view" function?

```
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    extra_context = extra_context or {}
    extra_context['model_title'] = Campaign._meta.verbose_name_plural
    return super(MymodelAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```